# react-beautiful-dnd: Reverse the stacking order?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

Is it possible to reverse the positioning when stacked on top of each other. For example I'd like an array of ["a", "b", "c"]

To be represented like this.

|------- C --------|

|------- B --------|

|------- A --------|

I know I can simple reorder the array but doing so will cause other side effects in the app.

Thank you so much.